# Django - initial value modelform

Tags: python, django, model

I would like to fix the initial value of a modelform  (model Flow) using data from another Model (Item). Though this does't seem to work. As instance_cf.feeder needs to be fueled by the model Flow I have the impression. How can  I solve this??

thanks to all

models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   feeder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

(...)

```
class Flow(models.Model):
   feeder = models.ForeignKey(Item, default="None", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

(...)

views.py:

```
def create_flow(request, itemslug):


 a = Item.objects.get(slug=itemslug).feeder

 if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = FlowForm(request.POST)

    if cf.is_valid():
        instance_cf = cf.save(commit=False)
        instance_cf.feeder = a
        instance_cf = cf.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Flow successfully added!')
        return redirect('items:create_flow', itemslug =itemslug) 
 else:
    cf = FlowForm()

 return render(request, 'items/create_flow.html', {'cf': cf})
```

error message :

Cannot assign "'XXXX'": "Flow.feeder" must be a "Item" instance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You aren't setting any initial values anywhere in this code. What value do you want to set, and where? And what in the code you give is not working?

Comment: instance_cf.feeder = a is not  working. The thing is that one of the attributes of the Flow model (feeder) needs to be pre-fixed. If no items exist in the Flow model obvious I can't refer to any other older items. Hence I am referring to the same attribute of another model (Item model)

Comment: But what does *not working" mean? What do you see? And please show the model definitions of Item and Flow.

Comment: Do you want the form to have the Item initially (before you Post it, and not just saved to the form after you post it)? This should work if your form is valid. If your form is not valid, you can check errors with something like 'else: print(cf.errors)' or - even better - place a breakpoint and debug

Comment: hi daniel / amchugh : I have included some additional info! Including the type error ! Thanks

Comment: you are assigning the value of the Item's field 'feeder' to a instead of the actual Item instance. then you try and assign this 'a' variable (which should be the Item instance) to the field on Flow which is a FK to Item model.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value of the Item's field 'feeder' to variable 'a' instead of the actual Item instance, then you try and assign this 'a' variable (which should be the Item instance) to the field on Flow which is a FK to Item model (and should have the instance of Item assigned to it).

change it to

```
 a = Item.objects.get(slug=itemslug)
```

---

**Also**

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    feeder = models.ForeignKey(Item, default="None", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

is kind of weird that you are assigning a text value as a default to a ForeignKey field (this might not just be 'weird' but straight up not allowed)

You should do something more like

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    feeder = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or to fit with your current convention

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    feeder = models.ForeignKey(Item, default=Item.objects.get(feeder="None"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I think you are having a little bit of trouble with understanding how the FK relationship works.